# {strip}: how to avoid unintended whitespace removal?

Tags: php, smarty, strip

```
{strip}
<div
     class="x"
>
{/strip}
```

becomes

```
<divclass="x">
```

And that is not what anyone would want.

So, the question: is there any way to avod this? Imagined approaches:

- replace new lines by spaces, using parameters or other smarty-functions
- add protected spaces that are not stripped/trimed

[This topic](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=41452) on their forum doesn't have a solution, (other than - add your own custom tag). Also, please don't offer solutions in raw PHP or any other languages / frameworks.

Comment: [It shouldn't.](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal a **function** [strip](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl), not a modifier ;)

Comment: Dear @c69, I edited your question as I had the very same problem but "turning new lines into spaces" did not come to my mind as a search query. Hope that's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either go with @dev's approach and [capture](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl) your data and run it through the [strip modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl):

```
{capture name="spaces"}
<div
     class="x"
> ... </div>
{/capture}
{$smarty.capture.spaces|strip:" "}
```

or run the captured content through a [regex_replace modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) (essentially doing the same as split, but with more overhead):

```
{$smarty.capture.spaces|regex_replace:"#\s+#":" "}
```

or drop in a new [custom block plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl) called trimwhitespace that makes use of the [outputfilter trimwhitespace](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/libs/plugins/outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php):

```
<?php
function smarty_block_trimwhitespace($params, $content, Smarty_Internal_Template $template, &$repeat)
{
  require_once SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR . 'outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php';
  return smarty_outputfilter_trimwhitespace($content, $template->smarty);
}
```

call this file block.trimwhitespace.php and place it in the plugins_dir. use it in your template:

```
{trimwhitespace}
<div
     class="x"
> ... </div>
{/trimwhitespace}
```

While both modifier approaches would work fine for simple HTML stuff, they'd break for content including `<script>` or `<pre>` tags. If you need those, you want to go with the wrapped outputfilter.

If you want all your output to be run through that filter, forget altering your templates and add `$smarty->loadFilter('output', 'trimwhitespace');` to your setup.

Answer (score 3):

To protect individual spaces:

```
{strip}
<div class="first{" "}
  {"second "}
  third">
{/strip}
```

becomes

```
<div class="first second third">
```

works fine for me with smarty v3.

Comment: Works also for Smarty v2.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware if it's possible to refrain from doing it in every template but rather on top in `header.tpl` and in the bottom in `footer.tpl`. It seems that Smarty tags are not transferred through the templates?

Answer (score 1):

Assign your code to a variable and try `{$articleTitle|strip:'&nbsp;'}`