# Form deleting spaces

Tags: php, html, forms

```html
<form action="class.php" method="POST">
  thread link:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="thread">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have this simple form. Upon entering a string starting with many spaces, something like

```
 "           test"
```

my PHP code

`echo 'test:'.$_POST['thread'];`

will print `test: test`. It will erase all spaces except one.

Where did all the spaces go and why does this happen?

Comment: Check this answer to strip spaces out of a string http://stackoverflow.com/a/7965076

Comment: I don't want to strip all spaces, I want to keep them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specification of HTMLs tells, renderer removes multiple spaces. That is useful in some cases. To avoid that, you can place content of this field in `<pre></pre>` block. Like that:

```
echo '<pre>test:'.$_POST['thread'].'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

The form does not delete spaces. Neither does your PHP code. The spaces are still there in resulting HTML document (generated by your PHP code in response to form submission). They just get rendered as a single space, since in most contexts, any sequence of whitespace characters in HTML content is equivalent to a single space. This is defined in CSS 2.1 spec, in the description of the [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) property.

Thus, to prevent the collapse of spaces, the simple way is to set `white-space: pre` in CSS. It also prevents line breaks in the content, but this is probably not a problem here. Using the `pre` element in HTML causes this setting, but it also sets font family to monospace.

So this is just a matter of HTML and CSS, independently of PHP. Example:

```html
<p>         Hello world!</p>
<p style="white-space: pre">         Hello world!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert whitespaces to html entities

```
  $thread =  str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $_POST['thread'])
```

and now `echo 'test:'.$thread` will output your text with whitespaces.

Comment: This seems legit, but why does ($_POST['thread']==="a") gives false when I input "a "? Does it have different values in HTML than PHP?

Comment: you should use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: Why? It still outputs the same even if I do.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc because `==` checks only values, `===` - value and type(e.g. int string etc) must be the same

Comment: And aren't both strings in this case?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc check it with `var_dump($_POST['thread'])` it will show you the type of your value

Answer (score 0):

This is the most basic thing about HTML. Any whitespace is equivalent and is treated as a single space.

You should never use multiple spaces to try to layout your text in HTML ( like you could do in Word for instance ). You should use css styles like margin or padding instead.

The answers that propose to replace the spaces with & nbsp; are correct, but they leave you on the wrong track.

Comment: That doesn't really answer question. OP tells, he wants to keep these spaces

Comment: It actually does answer it, hence the "why does this happen?"